# My Loop Won't Check All Elements Of Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void displayString (const char *sPtr);
void getString (char *[]);
int determinIfConvert (char);

int main ()
{
    char originalString[11] = { 0 };
    char convertedString[11];
    getString (originalString);
    displayString (originalString);

    // this loop runs through the "originalString" to check for the char: 'a'
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        determinIfConvert (originalString[i]);
    }
    system ("pause");
}

void getString (char *a[])  // this function gets a string
{
    printf ("enter 11 char string: \n");
    scanf ("%s", a);
}

// this program displays the inputstring
void displayString (const char *sPtr)
{
    for (; (*sPtr != '\0'); ++sPtr) {
        printf ("%c", *sPtr);
    }
}

int determinIfConvert (char *a)
{
    if (a == 97)            // this is a test condition. The goal is to
                            // check for all lowercase, but now i'm
                            // only entering "aaaaa"
    {
        printf ("Works");   // if it prints multiple"works"
                            // then i can continue my program
                            // but it only prints ONE "works" and freezes.
    }

}
```

At the moment I have a problem with my For Loop in `main()` not finishing. The goal is to enter a string of characters, and then check for lowercase ones. This will be done with the function `DeterminIfConvert(char)`. However, when I run through the loop element by element, it freezes after the second element. My test data is "aaaa" and it prints the "aaaa," so I know that my first two functions work just fine. I get to the loop, it goes through the first element, prints "works" and then freezes. :/

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' input format specifier, always include a max length modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer, so the user cannot overflow the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event..

Comment: regarding this line: `printf ("enter 11 char string: \n");`  the input buffer is only 11 characters long and the following '%s' format specifier will cause scanf() to always append a NUL byte to what ever the user enters.  So the max length of the string can only be 10 characters:  suggest: 1) change 11 to 10  2) modify the call to scanf() to: `if( 1 != scanf ("%10s", a) ) { // handle error }`

Comment: to check for lower case, given ascii characters, use `islower()`

Comment: regarding this line: `void getString (char *a[])`   This is saying it is passing an array of pointers to char.  Not what you want.  suggest: `void getString (char *a)`

Comment: this line: `for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {` will be checking one too far into the array.  suggest: `for (int i = 0;  originalString[i];  i++) {`

Comment: regarding: `system ("pause");`  this is not portable (not all OSs have a `pause` command.  suggest:  `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n');  getchar();`

Comment: the posted code contains 'magic' numbers. (I.E. 11)  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest; using a #define statement to give the 'magic' number a meaningful name, then using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple mistakes

```
void getString(char *a[])
```

should be

```
void getString(char a[])
```

Since you're sending the base address of an `array of char`, not an `array of pointer to char`

```
char *a[];  // array of pointer to char
char a[];   // array of char
```

---

```
 int determinIfConvert(char *a)
```

should be

```
int determinIfConvert(char a)
```

Since you're sending a `char`, not a `pointer to char`

```
char * a;    // pointer to char
char a;      // char
```

---

**NOTE:** 
Use the standard definition of `main()`

```
int main(void) //if no command line arguments.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are inputting an 11-char string, then you should be doing:

```
char originalString[12] = { 0 };
```

This is because you need 1 more character to store the null character `'\0'`.

That is probably why in your function `getString(...)`, the pointer exceeds the array bounds and might invoke undefined behavior.

Finally, your function prototype for `getString(...)` should be

```
void getString(char a[]); //without the *
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you have several other areas where you can improve your code.

Avoid using *magic numbers* in your code (e.g. `11`). Instead define a constant for the maximum characters in your string `#define MAXC 11` or you can use an `enum` instead `enum { MAXC = 11 };`

As it currently sits, you do not protect against overflowing your `11 character` array (which means your user can enter no more than `10 characters` plus room for the *nul-terminating* character). To protect against the user entering something more than `10`, you should use a *field-width* specifier with scanf:

```
    scanf ("%10s", a);
```

That doesn't solve your problems with `scanf`. You *must* check the return every time to insure the expected number of conversions takes place, e.g.:

```
if (scanf ("%10s", a) != 1) {
    fprintf (stderr, " -> error: invalid input.\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

That's better, but using `%s`, you cannot read a string containing whitespace, and you are still leaving a trailing `'\n'` in the *input buffer*. If the users enters `"my dog"`, you store `"my"` only. To fix part of the problem you can use a format specifier of `"%10[^\n]%*c"`. However, you must protect against an endless-loop if the user presses <kbd>[Enter]</kbd> without other input. To resolve all issues, and prevent leaving the trailing newline in the input buffer, you can use something like:

```
int getString (char *a)  // this function gets a string
{
    int c, rtn = 0;
    printf ("enter string (10 char or less): ");
    while ((rtn = scanf ("%10[^\n]%*c", a)) != 1) {
        if (rtn == EOF)
            break;
        fprintf (stderr, " -> error: invalid input, try again..\n");
        printf ("enter string (10 char or less): ");
        /* flush input buffer - to avoid endless loop */
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

All of which expose the difficulties using `scanf` for user input. A better approach may be to use `fgets` (or `getline`) to read the complete line of input.

Regardless whether you use `scanf` or `fgets`, etc.. you must take a bit of time and care in writing your input handlers to insure you try and cover all ways a user could muck up input. Below `fgets` is used just to present an alternative. You should also choose a return type that allows you to tell whether you have successfully received input or not. It might as well be a useful return such as the length of the input taken, etc..

The remainder of your level of pointer indirection issues have been addressed by other answers. Putting it all together, you could do something like:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 11

void displayString (const char *sPtr);
int getString (char *);
int determinIfConvert (char);

int main (void)
{
    char originalString [MAXC] = "";
    // char convertedString[MAXC] = "";  /* currently unused */
    if (!getString (originalString)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: getString failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    displayString (originalString);

    // this loop runs through the "originalString" to check for the char: 'a'
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        determinIfConvert (originalString[i]);
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;          /* main() is type 'int' and returns a value */
}

int getString (char *a)  // this function gets a string
{
    char *p = a;
    int c;
    size_t len = 0;

    printf ("enter string (10 char or less): ");
    for (;;) {
        p = fgets (a, MAXC, stdin);
        if (!p) break;          /* handle [CTRL+D]  */
        if (*p == '\n') {       /* handle empty str */
            fprintf (stderr, " -> error: invalid input, try again..\n");
            printf ("enter string (10 char or less): ");
            continue;
        }
        /* trim newline/flush input buffer */
        len = strlen (p);
        if (len && a[len - 1] == '\n')
            a[--len] = 0;
        else  /* user entered more than 10 chars */
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
        break;
    }

    return (int) len;
}

// this program displays the inputstring
void displayString (const char *sPtr)
{
    for (; *sPtr; sPtr++) {
        printf ("%c", *sPtr);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}

int determinIfConvert (char a)
{
    if (a == 97)
        printf ("Works\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getdispstr
enter string (10 char or less): my dog has fleas
my dog has
Works

$ ./bin/getdispstr
enter string (10 char or less):
 -> error: invalid input, try again..
enter string (10 char or less): my dog has fleas, my cat has none.
my dog has
Works
```

**With CTRL+D (EOF)**

```
$ ./bin/getdispstr
enter string (10 char or less): error: getString failed.
```

There are many ways to do this, this is just an example. Look over all the answers and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
  char originalString[11] = { 0 };
```

followed by this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        determinIfConvert(originalString[i]);
    }
```

is causing the problem. You see the array of char does not have elements post `index 0`. And yeah I believe what you are trying to attempt with 
`getString(originalString);` seems like you want to get `originalString` from user input which is not correctly executed in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You pass object of type **char** to a function accepting **char***

```
 char originalString[11] = { 0 };
 determinIfConvert(originalString[i]);

 int determinIfConvert(char *a)
```

Answer (score 0):

A string is nothing but a null terminated set of characters, so if you wish to have 11 characters in you string, you should be allocating 12 bytes to your
array, ie you may change :

```
char originalString[11] = { 0 };
```

to

```
char originalString[12] = ""; 

/* Here is the string is empty but because you use double quotes  
 * compiler understands that you are initializing a string, so '\0' is auto  
 * appended to the end of it by the compiler to mark the end of the string.
 */
```

So is the case with `convertedString[11]` change it to

```
char convertedString[12] = "";
```

Change

```
void getString(char *a[]);
```

to

```
void getString(char a[]); //char *a is also fine
```

Change

```
int determinIfConvert(char *a)
```

to

```
int determinIfConvert(char a) // You wish to check a character
```

You may wish to replace

```
scanf("%s", a);
```

with

```
fgets(a,12,stdin);
```

because scanf can't check for overflows but fgets can. Here you  can have up to 11 characters in the string. If an overflow occurs, the rest of the input is trimmed and '\0' is assigned to the 12th byte.

You may wish to use the `islower` function to check is a character is lowercase. So you may change

```
if (a == 97)
```

to

```
if (islower(a)) // check if a character is lowercase.
```

Remember you may need to include the `string.h` header to use `islower()`